# Asp.net form validation using Validation configuration file

Tags: asp.net, .net, validation

Currently I have a requirement to validate(server side)  forms in ASP.net (not MVC). We have several fields in our form which gets data from active directory. Instead of using inbuilt .net validation control, the requirement was to use a configuration setting for all validations, which can be easily edited.I am planning to use XML(or any other similar alternative) as configuration Editor.

Initially I thought (still thinking) this is simple task to achieve. But when I searched for similar implementation, i couldn't find one. Some of the implementation which i [saw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478956.aspx) uses a very complex approach. The whole idea was to keep the validation settings as simple and as dynamic as possible.

I would appreciate if anyone can direct me to a similar implementation or give suggestions with respect to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/256355/Microsoft-Enterprise-Library-5-0-Introduction-to-V) article very useful. It introduced me the validation block in Enterprise Library 5.0 which can be customized as per our requirement.